# Conditional rendering after new data available in props

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render specific piece of code only when props are available. I'm kind of new to react so I've been struggling with this issue.

I have side bar that will render a list it  looks something like this:

```
    renderList(){
    if(!this.props.graph.visibility){
      return <div></div>
    }else{
      this.props.graph.map((list) =>{
        <div>list.name</div>
      })
    }
  }
  <sideBar>
    {this.renderList()}
  </sideBar>
```

But what I've notice is that initially `this.props.graph` is empty, although it exist in my list of props only when an action have been fired from another component is when I receive the new data available from `this.props.graph`

Here is how it look before and after the action.

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

Action:

```
    export const SAVE_GRAPH = 'SAVE_GRAPH';
export const CHECK_GRAPH = 'CHECK_GRAPH';

export function saveGraph(graphTitle,firstMetric,secondMetric,graphType, graphCat) {
    return {
      type: SAVE_GRAPH,
      payload: {
        graphTitle, firstMetric,secondMetric,graphType,graphCat
      }
    }
}
export function checkGraph(visibility){
  return{
    type: CHECK_GRAPH,
    visibility:visibility
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
    import {
    SAVE_GRAPH,
    CHECK_GRAPH
  } from '../actions/saveGraph';

export default function saveGraph(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_GRAPH:
            return Object.assign({}, state,[action.payload])
        case CHECK_GRAPH:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              visibility: action.visibility
          });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Any idea of how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you include the state/redux state structure?

Comment: Have you looked into the React lifecycle methods?

Comment: @canaanseaton I know there is a method call componentWillRecieveProps but there is not much info on how to use it

Comment: @Matthew I've updated the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is empty when it is initialized.

`export default function saveGraph(state = {}, action) {`

The key aspect is `state = {}`.

visibility does not exist as a property when the state is initialized.
A solution is `...state = {visibility: false}...`

Alternately, you can define initialState above the function.

```
const initialState = {
    // this is the default value that will be supplied when the application is initialized
    visibility: false
};

export default function saveGraph(state = initialState, action) {
    // ...
}
```

From the redux documentation:

> Redux will call our reducer with an undefined state for the first time. This is our chance to return the initial state of our app

[image: Initial state redux example]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this component is a Class, and include the lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`. That method takes an argument for `newProps`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use initialState:

```
constInitialState = { visibility: false }

export default function saveGraph(state = initialState, action) {...}
```